# Do wars in Europe rarely start on a Wednesday?

Tags: europe, russia, warfare, ukraine, date

When the Russian ambassador to the EU, **Vladimir Chizhov**, was asked by the German newspaper Die Welt whether Russian armed forces would start to invade the Ukraine on Wednesday February 16th, as predicted by American intelligence sources, he answered that "***wars in Europe rarely start on a Wednesday***".

I wonder whether this is just a strange attempt at humour, or whether he is referencing a historical fact. Is this a quote by a historical figure? Was there ever an ill-fated attempt at an invasion that started on a Wednesday and lead to a superstition about Wednesdays? Was any famous military leader obsessed with the days on which to plan military action?

Comment: What time period are you interested in? What has your research shown? Have you checked the starting dates of any wars to see if there might be any truth to this? History SE generally requires some attempt at preliminary research. Please see our Help Centre on [Asking](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/asking). Thank you.

Comment: @LarsBosteen I don't think his comment was based on statistical analysis of European military history, and I don't propose that someone undertake such a thing. I just hoped that someone might recognize this as a quote or a preoccupation of a well-known figure.

Comment: Then I suggest you edit your question to make this clear. :)

Comment: I think his remark was not based on anything, except for the desire to deny that Russia was about to start an invasion.

Comment: Going through a [list of conflicts in Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_conflicts_in_Europe) can answer this question.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that the most recent war (the Russian invasion of Ukraine) started on February 24, i.e. a Thursday... whatever that means.